# How to return array from Zapier trigger

Tags: javascript, list, contacts, zapier

guys I'm trying to make an app on zapier. I've got action to create data when a contact is created, but I want to get all contact on the platform to save them in my database. How can I do that? I'm using the UI platform. I make a trigger to get the list, but I don't know how can I return the array, because super just return the first item.
Thank's for your help guys

Comment: Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using polling? If so, your polling URL should point to an API endpoint that returns the array of contacts.